# Importing a dictionary for word check

Tags: java, dictionary, import

I am making a Java project which involves the user to generate random letters and create a word that is worth a lot of points.

I was able to create the random letter generator, but I was thinking about when the user creates their word, how could I get my program to check and see if that word exists?

Is there a way to import a dictionary or some alternative? And how could I do that?

Comment: i am able to create a textbox which allows the users to type their input

Comment: Have a look at the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some free wordlists available that you can use.  Try this one: http://wordlist.aspell.net/ (download the zip file).

Once you have the word list, I would toss every word into a HashSet first, and then you can use the contains(String s) method to determine whether the word is in the dictionary or not.